# How to center this newsletter sign-up form?

Tags: css, web, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am trying to center the newsletter sign-up form from [here](http://Kloudtrader.com). I have tried everything but it just simply refuse to be centered. I am using the skeleton CSS framework.

Comment: Did you even connect/link the Skeleton's css file?

Comment: Can you replicate your issue with a smaller case and share here instead of giving a link to your website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code. i have no idea about  skeleton. bus its works.

```
<section class="news">
            <h2 class="">Get Notified for Early Access</h2>
            <form novalidate="" target="_blank" class="validate" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" method="post" action="//KloudTrader.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=8ce5d035a2693858b995c33e9&amp;id=d252a06fa4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="columns">
                        <label style="display:none" for="mce-EMAIL">
                            Email
                        </label>
                        <input type="email" id="mce-EMAIL" class="email required u-full-width" name="EMAIL" value="Enter your email">
                        <div class="clear" id="mce-responses">
                            <div style="display:none" id="mce-error-response" class="response"></div>
                            <div style="display:none" id="mce-success-response" class="response"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
                            <input type="text" value="" tabindex="-1" name="b_8ce5d035a2693858b995c33e9_d252a06fa4">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="columns">
                        <input type="submit" class="button u-full-width" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
            </form>
        </section>



.news {text-alig:center}
.news .columns {float: none; display: inline-flex;}
```

Comment: you can learn from here!!!   http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-responsive-layout-with-skeleton-widescreen--webdesign-7473

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't do it with only skeleton, but I made some fast solution:

```
<div class="container align-center">
                <div class="">
                    <label style="display:none" for="mce-EMAIL">
                        Email
                    </label>
                    <input type="email" style="width:20%; display:block; margin: 0 auto 1em;" value="Enter your email" name="EMAIL" class="email required u-full-width" id="mce-EMAIL">
                    <div class="clear" id="mce-responses">
                        <div style="display:none" id="mce-error-response" class="response"></div>
                        <div style="display:none" id="mce-success-response" class="response"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
                        <input type="text" value="" tabindex="-1" name="b_8ce5d035a2693858b995c33e9_d252a06fa4">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="three columns">
                    <input type="submit" class="button u-full-width" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe">
                </div>
            </div>
```